# Can't import SQL DB with WP-CLI due to Access Denied (Error 1045)

Tags: sql, wordpress, wp-cli

I have been in the process of moving a load of WordPress sites over from a tsoHost server to Ploi using WP-CLI and, after much trial and error, I have now managed to transfer 11/12 of the sites.

The last one (adultsmareach.co.uk), at the last step is throwing an error though... This has been my process so far:

- PuTTy to existing server and `zip -r adultsmareach.zip *`
- phpMyAdmin and export the appropriate SQL database (wwwadultsmareach_wp_qexte.sql)
- Go to Ploi server and create new domain "adultsmareach.co.uk", project type "WordPress"
- SFTP the ZIP and SQL files to the new domain folder
- PuTTY to Ploi server and `unzip adultsmareach.zip`
- Edit `wp-config.php` so that DB connections settings point to `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`:

NOTE: in previous sites the hostname has just been localhost but for this site (for some reason) it is localhost:3306, not sure if that's the issue as that's the   only thing I spotted different from this and previous sites...

- In PuTTY use `wp db import wwwadultsmareach_wp_qexte.sql` at this point I get the error:

`Error: Failed to get current SQL modes. Reason: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'wwwadultsmareach_wp_logbn'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Strange that it is still trying to login `@localhost` and not `127.0.0.1`. To try and fix this, as it happened this way with a couple of other sites, I went to the ploi server and added a new database with the correct name, user and password, then went to "edit" and added it to the site. This then allowed me to succesfully use the `wp db import database.sql` command, but that won't work this time...

Can anyone spot what might be the issue here? I also tried putting `define( 'DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1:3306' );` in `wp-config.php` but that didn't help either.

Thanks.